# ArgumentOutOfRangeException was Unhandled C# error

Tags: c#, exception, invalid-argument

InvalidArgument=Value of '4' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index

here is my code

```
   if (lvnames.Items.Count > 0)
   {
         for (int x = 0; x < lvScratch.Items.Count; x++)
         {
           **lvnames.Items[x].SubItems[4].Text = lvnamestemp.Items[x].SubItems[0].Text;**
         }
   }
   else
   {

            MessageBox.Show("No Record", "Empty", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

   }
```

my lvnames.Items has 4 colums
and my lvnamestemp has 3 columns

i got  that error InvalidArgument=Value of '4' on the bold code when i run the code

Comment: Is your code like this at first? I edited it and change your bracket position,sorry.

Comment: tried using index of 0 instead of 4,If no error is present, it means that 4 is out of range.

Comment: add a blank columm and use 4 (is it possible?) It is usually my dumb way solving programming problems Xb

Comment: i already added 5 columns on my lvnames but that still the same error... i know this sounds crazy for simple problem on programming but i cant figure it out, i need some sort of idea. thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

" my lvnames.Items has 4 colums "

But you are accessing the 5th column with this code:

```
lvnames.Items[x].SubItems[4]
```

0 1 2 3 4  (4 is the fifth item).

Comment: Nice , i don't know about that. @OP index is count from0

Comment: If you have 1 column, the index is 0.  If you have two columns the index goes from 0 to 1.  If you have three columns the indexes are 0, 1, 2.  etc.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much all arrays and collections are zero-based in .NET.  The actual number of columns in a ListView is irrelevant to the number of subitems in a ListViewItem; all that matters is the number of subitems you added.  Usually they are the same though.  If you have four columns then you probably added four subitems, so they will be at indexes 0, 1, 2 and 3.  Obviously 4 is not a valid index then.

Comment: Who cares about your C++?  How's your C#? ;-)  As I said, it really doesn't matter how many columns there are in the `ListView`.  The `SubItems` collection of a `ListViewItem` is independent of that.  All that matters is the number of subitems you added.  Note that the item itself is its own first subitem.  If index 4 is invalid then that means that you have added three or fewer subitems to the item.  If you want to access the subitem at index 4 then you have to add one, i.e. you have to add at least four subitems to the item.

Comment: How many times can I say the same thing?  The number of columns that you have added to your ListView is **IRRELEVANT**!  All that matters is the number of subitems you have added to that item.  You can add a hundred columns to your ListView if you want but if you only add two subitems to your item then you will only have subitems at indexes 0, 1 and 2.  You haven't added enough subitems to the item.  It's that simple.  **STOP** thinking about the number of columns in the ListView because it has **ABSOLUTELY NOTHING** to do with your issue.